# Magento 5 products on home page with all options

Tags: magento

I want to build a shop using magento, but I will only have 5 products with all the options (size, quantity, colour and so on) on the home page, maybe some on has done something similar and could point me to the right direction?

P.S

I googled :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the easiest way to achieve this is to create a category with those 5 products and set is as the homepage of your webshop. You can find this option under `System > Configuration > Web > Default Web URL`.

So instead of using the default `cms` value, use the following value:
`catalog/category/view/id/<your_category_id>`

The category ID is visible on the category edit page in the admin.

Managing this page is just like you would normally treat your product list / category pages.

Answer (score -1):

try to download the magento and install the demo store....
And u can use http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base this to aswer the basic.